# I can't update to R version 4

Tags: r, installr

I have downloaded the latest version of R and I have tried to run code in Jupyter notebook that will update.My code and the output below:

```
`# installing/loading the latest installr package:
install.packages("installr"); library(installr) # install+load installr
updateR() # updating R.'
```

Output I get:
Warning message:
"package 'installr' is in use and will not be installed"
Error in winDialog(type = "ok", message = message_text): winDialog() cannot be used non-interactively
Traceback:

1. updateR()
2. check.for.updates.R(print_R_versions, GUI = GUI, page_with_download_url = paste0(cran_mirror,
   .     "bin/windows/base/"))
3. winDialog(type = "ok", message = message_text)
4. stop("winDialog() cannot be used non-interactively")

When I type:
'install.packages("installr")

```
library(installr)

updateR()'
```

I get the following message:

'package 'installr' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked

The downloaded binary packages are in
C:\Users\tadhg\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpkFhJyM\downloaded_packages
Warning message:
"package 'installr' was built under R version 3.6.3"
Welcome to installr version 0.23.2

More information is available on the installr project website:
https://github.com/talgalili/installr/

Contact: tal.galili@gmail.com
Suggestions and bug-reports can be submitted at: https://github.com/talgalili/installr/issues

```
        To suppress this message use:
        suppressPackageStartupMessages(library(installr))
```

Error in winDialog(type = "ok", message = message_text): winDialog() cannot be used non-interactively
Traceback:

1. updateR()
2. check.for.updates.R(print_R_versions, GUI = GUI, page_with_download_url = paste0(cran_mirror,
   .     "bin/windows/base/"))
3. winDialog(type = "ok", message = message_text)
4. stop("winDialog() cannot be used non-interactively")
   '

Comment: I'm assuming you've contacted Mr. Galili. Did he have any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem.

This helped a bit:

```
 updateR(GUI=FALSE)
```

However then it got:

```
The file was downloaded successfully into:
 /tmp/RtmpbZdEgx/R-4.2.0-win.exe 

Running the installer now...
sh: 1: /tmp/RtmpbZdEgx/R-4.2.0-win.exe: Permission denied

Installation status:  FALSE . Removing the file:
 /tmp/RtmpbZdEgx/R-4.2.0-win.exe 
 (In the future, you may keep the file by setting keep_install_file=TRUE) 
[1] FALSE
Warning message:
In get.installed.R.folders() :
  Could not find any R installation on your system. (You might have installed your R version on 'c:\R' without sub folders...
```

For me it seems that this package is designed for Windows only. (I'm using Ubuntu).